# Android Navigation Component: deep link to a different Activity

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

My app's design looks like this: I have different features, where each feature is in a distinct module: each module has an Activity with a navigation graph. Features (modules) are indipendent: from a feature I start a different feature using startActivity with implicit Intents.
Now I would like to open a specific destination (not the first one) on another Activity.
What's the best way to achieve this?
Implicit deep linkds always display a disambiguation window that I don't want.
Explicit deep links require a Pending Intent and a notification, but I just want to click a button and navigate to my destination. Moreover, I can't use a Pending Intent if my modules are indipendent.